# Shortcut for self.__class__

Tags: python-3.x

Sometimes I find myself accessing class members. In one project I even had class definitions inside a class definition.

In such cases I often find mysql typing `self.__class__.<member_name>` or `self.__class__.<contained_class_name>`. In about all use cases `self.__class__` is more characters than the actual class name, hence using `self.__class__` is annoying. However,

- I don't want to hardcode the class name inside the class definition,
- `self.__class__.some_attribute` is not (always) the same as using the class name, e.g. `MyClass.some_attribute` and I want the behaviour of the former

So I was wondering. Is there some shorter notation of `self.__class__`?

Comment: [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)`(self)`?

Comment: why don't you do self.cls = self.__class__ in __ init __?