# Is there a class-and-instance method in Python?

Tags: python, class

Is there a way of creating a method with this signature?

```
def(self, cls, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    self.instance = cls.some_class_default
```

I'm aware of instance methods:

```
def(self, arg1, arg2):
   self.instance = some_default_literal_value
```

and class methods:

```
@classmethod
def(cls, arg1, arg2)
   cls.some_class_default = arg1
```

But is there a conventional way to mark a method that uses both **instance variables** and **class variables**?

Even within a method, [`self.__class__.some_class_default`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283087/shortcut-for-self-class) feels cumbersome, so such a method feels like it could be valuable.

Comment: It sounds like a decorator you could easily write yourself. I don't think this is something that's needed often enough for there to be a standard decorator.

Comment: Why do you need this? In OOP, it's rare to need to refer to the instance's class directly, as that's likely to bypass inheritance.

Comment: This is a bit too hypothetical to get at a real answer. Can you give us an exact use case?

Comment: As I continued coding after writing this question, I found myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15189304/1048186     I think that the problem was that I was trying to access a class variable within the default parameters of a method.

Comment: You can always get `cls` with `type(self)`; I don't seen any benefit to having a specific method that automatically gets passed both. The main point of a class method is not so much that the class is passed automatically as the fact that the class is passed whether you invoke the method from the class *or* from an instance of the class.

Comment: @chepner Can you elaborate or link to an answer on that?  The first answer [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod) didn't explain this to me at all.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to access the class variables directly through the self reference, e.g.:

```
def(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(self.some_class_default)
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to change the method signature just to access a class variable from an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the class is trivial:

```
def foo(self, x, y, z):
    cls = type(self)
    ...
```

Adding an entire other kind of method to do this automatically

```
class Foo
    @combomethod
    def bar(self, cls, x, y, z):
        ...
```

seems like it would have minimal benefit.